# HTML populating dropdown list from array created in Python - cs50 Finance

Tags: javascript, python, html, arrays, html.dropdownlistfor

I am working on the cs50 Finance problem and need to create a dropdown list that is dynamic and changes depending on the user. The goal is to get the user's stocks from a database and put those options in the dropdown menu.

Right now, I have the following code in my html file, where "symbols" is an array taken from my python file:

```
<form action="/sell" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="symbol">
            <option disabled selected value="Symbol">Symbol</option>

        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" min="0" name="shares" placeholder="Shares" type="number">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sell</button>
</form>
<script>
    var select = document.getElementByName("symbol");
    var options = {{ symbols }};

    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var opt = options[i];
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el);
    }
</script>
```

When I print out my "symbols" array in a separate div to make sure the values are correct, it prints correctly to show the two stocks: ['AAPL' 'F']

However, the dropdown list will not populate. When I go into the Javascript console, I get an error at the "var options = {{ symbols }};" line because the apostrophes are represented by "'" and javascript isn't recognizing them. I think this is what's stopping my code from populating the dropdown list.

I've tried using a list instead of an array, removing the apostrophes in python and even using php instead, but nothing has worked. Any thoughts?

Comment: which templating language are you using?

Comment: What templating language/web framework are you using?  You should be able to use that language's for loop to generate the options in the HTML markup.  Unless using JS is a requirement for this, that would be cleaner.

Comment: I believe the templating language is Jinja. All we learned in addition to html in this section of the course was JS, but we never actually learned about templating languages, so I did not even realize I could do something else. This is helpful, thank you @MattDale!

Comment: If {{ symbols }} is really replace by ['AAPL' 'F'] it is not going to work because items in an array should be separated by a coma

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jinja or similar templating language, this would create the option items in the template using your symbols array:

```
<div class="form-group">
<select class="form-control" name="symbol">
    <option disabled selected value="Symbol">Symbol</option>
       {% for option in symbols %}
       <option value={{option}}>{{option}}</option>
       {% endfor %}
</select>
</div>
```